# Hosting an H2 database and accepting connections

Tags: java, h2

I've looked all over for this for quite a while so I'm just going to ask it here;

How do I set up an H2 db in server mode so I can connect to it via the internet from a different machine?  How do I start the engine in server mode and leave it running on a machine to accept connections?  I can forward the ports and everything fine, it's just getting the engine in "receiving" mode that I'm dumb about.

I'm sorry, I've really looked everywhere.  I want to be able to connect to the db and add data from a mobile app.  All of the app and transmission data is working great, I just need to be able to run a server with the db on it and receive the data.  Any tutorial or documentation that is clearer than the stock H2 server mode documentation would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For security reasons, by default the H2 servers (including the TCP server) are [protected against remote access](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#remote_access). The error message you get on the client should be clear this. You have to explicitly enable remote access using `-tcpAllowOthers` (for the TCP server):

```
java -cp h2.jar org.h2.tools.Server -tcp -tcpAllowOthers
```

This will only start the TCP server - see the documentation for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ java -cp h2.jar -Dh2.binAddress=0.0.0.0 org.h2.tools.Server
```

See http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#server_bind_address